# Why does CrossTable fail with "'x' must have at least 2 elements" on a vector with a single value?

Tags: r

```
library(gmodels)    
a <- c(4,4,4,4,4)
CrossTable(a, chisq=FALSE, prop.chisq=FALSE)
```

produces: Error in chisq.test(t, correct = FALSE) : 
  'x' must at least have 2 elements

```
a <- c(4,5,6,7,8)
CrossTable(a, chisq=FALSE, prop.chisq=FALSE)
```

produces the frequency table you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is a single cell: a count of 5 of the value 4. `CrossTable()` wants at least 2 cells in the table.